# Is it posible to have 2 Select statements with 2 different outputs in 1 query?

Tags: mysql, sql, ms-access

So I'm using MS Access to have users access a mysql database. I don't use linked tables rather connect to the database using ODBC DAO connections.

I'm generating a report which at the bottom gives the balance of the account. So far in my query I have been able to get all the data I need from the database except for the balance. Reason is that all the data I pull from database is filtered by a where statement between two dates and a company id. For the balance however I need another set of results giving me the sum of a whole column.

Reason I need to put this on a single sql query is because I will then pass this query to the recordsource of the report thus I cant use two queries.

I tried to use UNION but it doesnt work since I'm using a continuous form to show all results it creates more rows to fit for the second select statement.

This works as intended.

```
SELECT tbl10prepago.NumeroFactura, tbl10prepago.Fecha, tbl12vehiculosprepago.Tablilla, tbl11empleadosprepago.NombreEmpleado, tbl10prepago.Litros, tbl10prepago.CostoLitro, tbl10prepago.CantidadDinero, tbl13companiasprepago.NombreCompania, tbl13companiasprepago.Concepto, tbl5localidades.NombreLocalidad, tbl5localidades.DireccionPostal, tbl5localidades.Telefono 
FROM (tbl10prepago INNER JOIN tbl12vehiculosprepago ON tbl10prepago.IdVehiculo = tbl12vehiculosprepago.ID)
INNER JOIN tbl11empleadosprepago ON tbl10prepago.IdEmpleado = tbl11empleadosprepago.ID 
INNER JOIN tbl13companiasprepago ON tbl10prepago.CompaniaID = tbl13companiasprepago.ID 
INNER JOIN tbl5localidades ON tbl13companiasprepago.LocalidadServicio = tbl5localidades.ID 
WHERE tbl10prepago.Fecha BETWEEN '" & Format(Me.Text40, "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss") & "' AND '" & Format(Me.Text42, "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss") & "' 
AND tbl10prepago.CompaniaID = " & Me.Combo34.Column(0) & " 
ORDER BY tbl10prepago.Fecha;
```

What I need to add is this:

```
SELECT SUM(tbl14pagoprepago.pago) as [BALANCE] 
FROM tbl14pagoprepago
WHERE tbl14pagoprepago.IDCompania = " & Me.Combo34.Column(0) & "
```

And not add it to the first Select results or filter by date also.

Thank you all in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

union will only work if you have same number of columns. What I can think of is you can add this `balance` field as new column.

```
SELECT tbl10prepago.NumeroFactura, tbl10prepago.Fecha, tbl12vehiculosprepago.Tablilla, tbl11empleadosprepago.NombreEmpleado, tbl10prepago.Litros, tbl10prepago.CostoLitro, tbl10prepago.CantidadDinero, tbl13companiasprepago.NombreCompania, tbl13companiasprepago.Concepto, tbl5localidades.NombreLocalidad, tbl5localidades.DireccionPostal, tbl5localidades.Telefono, 
    (SELECT SUM(tbl14pagoprepago.pago) FROM tbl14pagoprepago
        WHERE tbl14pagoprepago.IDCompania = " & Me.Combo34.Column(0) & ") as [Balance]
FROM (tbl10prepago INNER JOIN tbl12vehiculosprepago ON tbl10prepago.IdVehiculo = tbl12vehiculosprepago.ID)
INNER JOIN tbl11empleadosprepago ON tbl10prepago.IdEmpleado = tbl11empleadosprepago.ID 
INNER JOIN tbl13companiasprepago ON tbl10prepago.CompaniaID = tbl13companiasprepago.ID 
INNER JOIN tbl5localidades ON tbl13companiasprepago.LocalidadServicio = tbl5localidades.ID 
WHERE tbl10prepago.Fecha BETWEEN '" & Format(Me.Text40, "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss") & "' AND '" & Format(Me.Text42, "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss") & "' 
AND tbl10prepago.CompaniaID = " & Me.Combo34.Column(0) & " 
ORDER BY tbl10prepago.Fecha;
```